# Пропала ссылка на профиль в мобильной версии

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, профиль-участника, мобильная-версия

Еще недавно совсем она была, а сегодня исчезла.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как теперь попасть в свой профиль в мобильной версии?

Comment: [Мобильная версия планомерно упраздняется](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367609/339911). Новые дефекты будут закрываться как [статус-отклонено].

Comment: @αλεχολυτ окей, я это уже читал. А что делать то? Я не против, пусть отпиливают, только замены пока не видно, куда смотреть? Они решили удалить мобильную версию через ненависть пользователей отпиливая фичи от нее по одной?

Comment: Замена - это адаптивный дизайн. Который в пределе должен одинаково хорошо смотреться на экранах любых размеров.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ к сожалению, для мобильных экранов пока оно не походит. Колонка текста вопроса занимает 2/3 экрана. Остальное - белые поля. Вы сами то с мобильника пробовали? Ладно, я понял, к черту мобильники, только пк, только хардкор )

Comment: я с мобильного приложение StackExchange использую. Оно, правда, тоже считается устаревшим.

Comment: при словах "адаптивный дизайн" у меня уже начинается нервный тик. Обычно им можно пользоваться только в довольно узких пределах разрешений экрана.

Comment: @Эникейщик всё зависит от адаптивности этого самого дизайна. В 99% случаев это полуфабрикат, как и на SE.

Comment: _Вернули ссылку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На MSE завели об этом баг [Link to own profile has disappeared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368666/339911), который <s>планируют исправить</s> уже исправлен.

Способ обхода на момент наличия проблемы:

На текущий момент все ссылки (кроме Вопросов) из меню мобильной версии сайта ведут на полную версию сайта:

> [image: Меню мобильной версии]

Далее в шапке полной версии уже можно перейти в свой профиль:

> [image: Метки]

Профиль при этом откроется в мобильной версии:

> [image: Профиль мобильной версии]